# Валидация и save()

Tags: php, yii, валидация

С установлением каптчи начал натыкаться на проблему, что часто не проходит save() после валидации.

Тоесть опишу проблему:

У меня есть код:

```
...
if(!$HelpdeskModel->validate())
{
// сюда я попадаю всегда без проблемно 
...
if(!$HelpdeskModel->save())   throw new Exception('HelpdeskModel');
// а вот save() срабатывает обычно со 2 или 3 попытки, а в первых случаях выбрасывает Exception
...
}
...
```

Такое я стал наблюдать после установки стандартной каптчи yii. Далее я знаю, что save() вызывает валидацию еще раз и видимо каптча меняется почему то и бывает глюки, если же сделать save(false), то все нормально работает.

Однако объясните пожалуйста 3 вопроса:
1) почему save() вызывает валидацию, зачем это ? 
2) какого черта происходит ситуация, когда после validate() меняется каптча и save() уже не проходит 
3) безопасно ли использовать save(fasle) даже после validate() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) почему save() вызывает валидацию, зачем это?

Для того чтобы в простых ситуациях сохранять данные одной строкой, чтобы в контроллере было как можно меньше кода. Посмотрите любой стандартный контроллер сгенерированный через gii. Там нет явного вызова validate(), есть только save().

> 2) какого черта происходит ситуация, когда после validate() меняется каптча и save() уже не проходит

Ваша проблема именно в том, что валидация в контроллере вызывается дважды. Капча сбрасывается в [`CCaptchaAction::validate()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/widgets/captcha/CCaptchaAction.php#L174). По умолчанию, после трех проверок. Это значение устанавливается параметром [`CCaptchaAction::$testLimit`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/widgets/captcha/CCaptchaAction.php#L51).

У вас получается:

- Заполняется форма и отправляется на сервер
- Сервер выполняет validate() - (1-я проверка)
- Что-то заполнено неправильно, сервер возвращает форму на дозаполнение
- Дозаполняется форма и отправляется на сервер
- Сервер выполняет validate() - (2-я проверка)
- Что-то опять заполнено неправильно, сервер возвращает форму на дозаполнение
- Еще раз дозаполняется форма и отправляется на сервер
- Сервер выполняет validate() - (3-я проверка)
- Все правильно, сервер выполняет save() (и тут выполняется 4-я проверка при которой сбрасывается код капчи, и эта проверка не проходит)

Решение проблемы - выполнять валидацию один раз. Либо одним вызовом save(), либо связкой validate() и save(false).

> 3) безопасно ли использовать save(fasle) даже после validate()?

Если перед save(false) был выполнен validate(), то безопасно. Этот случай - один из вариантов уместного использования save(false).

Comment: больше спасибо за объяснение, вопрос решен.